# C++ map custom comparator using multiple object properties

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl

Let's say I have a map of students with `ID` as the key and `Student` object as the value. Here's the illustration:

```
struct Student{
  int id;
  int score;
  string name;
}

map<int, Student> students;
```

I want to sort the map in the following order: `Sort the students based on their test score, the student with lower ID comes first if they got the same score`

Is it possible to make a custom comparator using multiple object attributes? How can I do that?

I'm using the map because I also need the random access, is there any better approach instead of using `map` for this case?

UPDATE

I've changed the key with a new Object `Mapkey` with ID and score as the properties. And then I sort the map by comparing those properties.

But the problem is: it's kinda tricky to get the student value from the map since the score changes over time and I have to update the key. I'm wondering if there's a better and simpler solution.

Here's my implementation:

```
struct Mapkey {
    int id;
    int score;
};

struct cmp {
    bool operator()(const Mapkey &p1, const Mapkey &p2) const {

        if (p1.score == p2.score) {
            return p1.id < p2.id;
        }

        return p1.score > p2.score;

    }
};
map<Mapkey, Student*, cmp> sectionMap;
```

Comment: Absolutely! What is your attempt? map provides O(logN) access. map can only order on key. So may you want std::set.

Comment: I want to store the students where I can get students with the highest and the lowest score. But I also want to have the fastest way to get the student data by their ID, is it achievable if I use std::set? @CaptainGiraffe

Comment: Also, the score will be updated over time, so I need the fastest way to pop, reinsert, and sort the data again

Comment: It is understood what you want, but can you show your attempt at implementing this comparator, and explain, ***specifically*** what your question is, what problem are you having with your comparator? Do you know how to implement a custom map comparator?

Comment: I just posted my implementation @SamVarshavchik

Comment: Since the score changes over time, including it in the key is a very bad idea. If you need to update a score, you cant avoid popping the old score key and then inserting the new score key

Comment: @Sigmalalalala Please check out my edited answer using a vector of structures.

Comment: The comparator looks fine to me. However, map keys are always `const`, and once in the map they cannot be modified in place. It doesn't matter how the comparator works, this is always the case. To change a key, the key and its value get removed from the map and a new key and the same value get added. There are no other alternative. C++ just doesn't work any other way. If somewhere in the program the key gets modified how could a map know that it must magically re-sort itself, it can't.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, then you want to sort your `Student` objects based on their test scores first. In case they have the same score, then their ID is used as a secondary key instead.

I would recommend using a class for this. You can use the comparison operator to achieve what you want the following way:

```
bool operator< (const Student& left, const Student& right)
{
    if (left.score == right.score)
        return left.id < right.id;
    else
        return left.score < right.score;
}
```

You can place your objects in an `array` or a `vector`, it is really up to you.

***Edit:*** an alternative solution by Remy:

```
bool operator< (const Student& left, const Student& right)
{
    return std::tie(left.score, left.id) < std::tie(right.score, right.id);
}
```

***Edit2:*** Here is the complete implementation using a vector of structures. If this is not what you were looking for, then I give up.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Student
{
    int id;
    int score;
    std::string name;

    // Constructor
    Student(int a, int b, std::string s) : id(a), score(b), name(s) {}

    // Operator overloading
    bool operator < (const Student& obj) const
    {
        if (score == obj.score)
            return id < obj.id;
        else
            return score < obj.score;
    }

    // Printing
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "id: " << id << ", score: " << score << ", name: " << name << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Student> students;

    students.push_back(Student(1, 55, "A"));
    students.push_back(Student(4, 78, "D"));
    students.push_back(Student(3, 55, "C"));
    students.push_back(Student(2, 55, "B"));
    students.push_back(Student(5, 65, "E"));

    std::sort(students.begin(), students.end(), std::less<Student>());
    //std::sort(students.begin(), students.end()); // You can use this too
    std::cout << "Sorted vector:" << '\n';

    for (auto it = students.begin(); it != students.end(); ++it)
        it->print();

    std::cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Output of the code above:

```
Sorted vector:
id: 1, score: 55, name: A
id: 2, score: 55, name: B
id: 3, score: 55, name: C
id: 5, score: 65, name: E
id: 4, score: 78, name: D
```

Comment: This can be greatly simplified using `std::tie()`, eg: `bool operator< (const Student& left, const Student& right){ return std::tie(left.score, left.id) < std::tie(right.score, right.id); }`